# supply two board with one battery

Tags: voltage

I have build a little circuit that play an audio file each time a switch is released.
I used a voice board based on an ISD1820 
and an amplifier based on LM386.

[image: photo]

Everything works fine with a couple of aaa batteries for the amplifier and a button cell battery for the voice board.
Since i want to put this inside a box i'm trying to use only the aaa batteries; but if i connect the two boards to the batteries no sound is played. I can only heard a click sound on the speaker each time the key is released.

Unfortunately i can't find specific datasheet for the boards so i can't figure how to solve this. I hope someone can give me an hint.

Comment: Did you connect all the grounds together?

Comment: Check all your connections. Something is probably miswired. Looking at the picture, it looks like you connected red wire to blue bus bar on one side of proto-board, and red bus bar on other side. Try to use a consistent scheme for power connections. Red for + and black for - is very common.

Comment: New photo sorry for the bad wiring. i don't think it's a wiring problem, can be that i need a voltage regulator like @AdityaRachmanPutra said ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use different source for your project then you isolate both module from each other 'noise', or in this case the change of voltage caused by the osciliation of audio signal. Then when you connect the two source together, then both would share the noise (I mean the audio signal alone probably change the supply voltage, you can check this with multimeter/osciloscope when you use different supply). Then when you connect both, its either the change messing with the voltage which should be stable, or the stiff supply makes the audio signal's information change.

My suggestion is to isolate the two modules source, by using voltage regulator or just simple L-C filter shhould work.

Hope it helps, Cheers

Comment: I think you are right i have it tested with a multimeter. So, just to be sure, i need to put a voltage regulator after the battery pack and connect the boards to it?

Comment: a simple 78xx and some capacitor should do the trick @LuigiDB
and yes, put it after the battery pack and before the boards

Comment: Thanks I'll see what regulator I can find. But since i need 3v  for the boards i need more than 3v batteries; it's better use 3 aaa batteries or a 9v battery.